# Solspace Freeform: redirect to URI other than template_group/template

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a form at the URL `https://domain.tld/segment_1/segment_2/form`, and would like to redirect (on success) to `https://domain.tld/segment_1/segment_2/form/thank-you`.

When I do: `return="segment_1/segment_2/form/thank-you"` it doesn't work.
Is this possible?

Comment: Where **does** it return to?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  I do this all the time, using the thank-you segment in a conditional to display a message to the submitter.

Comment: At the moment it returns to the same page.

Comment: If I manually add a thank you segment, the template correctly displays the thank you conditional content.

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is a bug, but my opening tag is this:

```
{exp:freeform:form
        form_name="artwork_information_enquiry"
        form:role="form"
        form:id="request-info-form"
        form:novalidate="novalidate
        return="{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/success"
        required="first_name|last_name|email|enquiry_artwork_title|enquiry_artwork_img_url|enquiry_country"
        secure_action="yes"
        secure_return="yes"
        inline_errors="yes"
}
```

If I change the order of the return param (more towards the top) it works!

```
{exp:freeform:form
    form_name="artwork_information_enquiry"
    return="{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/success"
    form:role="form"
    form:id="request-info-form"
    form:novalidate="novalidate
    required="first_name|last_name|email|enquiry_artwork_title|enquiry_artwork_img_url|enquiry_country"
    secure_action="yes"
    secure_return="yes"
    inline_errors="yes"
}
```